# how to use log4js in test case with karma?

Tags: karma-runner, log4js-node

currently I need to add log4js support in my test case, like below:

```
it(' QuestionController saveQuestion method Testing ',  inject(function(localStorageService) {
    ***var log4js = require('log4js');
    var logger = log4js.getLogger();
    logger.debug("Some debug messages");***

    expect({}).toEqual(localStorageService.get('questionInfoStorage'));

  }));
```

I have tried to include the log4js js and repire js  file in *karma.conf.js* file, it is not working and giving some error like *"Module name "events" has not been loaded yet for context"* something.

Is there anybody coming the same issue previously? thanks advance!